# How to create relationship in Laravel 5 which will collect records of own model mentioned in pivot table?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 tables users, companies and pivot table with user_id, company_id.
I can't get users, which belongs to my company **inside User model**.
Tried like

```
belongsToMany('App\User','companies_users','company_id','user_id' );
```

but I get relation with wrong users.

Comment: How are you using the relationship? What's your query?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir User::where('id',$user->id)->with('myCompany')->get()  ,it is for director who has only one company.

Comment: Is `myCompany` the relationship you posted?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are having a `belongsToMany` relationship between the `User` and `Company`, the `User` belongs to more than one `Company`. To get users of the companies of a particular `User` will not be straight forward. If you are sure that is exactly what you want, then do this:

```
//inside the User model
public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Company');
    }

//inside the User model
public function companiesusers()
    {
        $users= new Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

        foreach($this->companies as $company)
        {
            $users = $users->merge($company->users->get());
        }

        return $users->unique();
    }

//inside the Company model
    public function users()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('User');
        }
```

Then you can get a user's `companiesusers` like so:

```
User::first()->companiesusers();
```

Comment: Elisha, some issues with foreach, I've tried dd($company->users) - it shows users, but  dd($company->users->get()) shows  Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed...